# Most efficient way to have a live countdown

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I am writing an app that includes a countdown. The countdown is displayed on a label, however I am not sure if I am updating the label most efficiently. I am using a timer with an interval of 1 second. Is there any way that would consume less resources? Also, will this crash on older devices?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//Create Calendar for NSDates
gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];

//Create NSDate lunchTime based on Now
now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *compsOfNow = [gregorian components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit |NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSEraCalendarUnit)fromDate:now];
[compsOfNow setHour:12];
[compsOfNow setMinute:50];
lunchTime = [gregorian dateFromComponents:compsOfNow];

//Create timer and set text
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTicked:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
lunchCountdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i:%i", difference.hour, difference.minute, difference.second];

}

- (void)timerTicked:(NSTimer*)timer {
now = [NSDate date];
difference = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:now toDate:lunchTime options:0];
lunchCountdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i:%i", difference.hour, difference.minute, difference.second];
NSLog(@"Timer Ticked");
```

Your input is appreciated,

Thanks,

HBhargava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems fine to me... just remember to invalidate the timer once you are done with it.(which you are not doing as of now.)